# What does it mean for a field theory to be invariant?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, definition, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, invariants

In this paper [A. N. Schellekens, Conformal field theory p.8](https://www.nikhef.nl/%7Et58/CFT.pdf) they mention the following

> If a field theory has a conserved, traceless energy momentum tensor, it is invariant
> both under general coordinate transformations and Weyl transformations.

What is meant with 'a *field theory* is invariant'? Is the action invariant? The fields? The equations of motion? All of the above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The action, yes. The equations of motion, therefore also yes. But the fields themselves, no. That's like expecting a rotation of axes to preserve Cartesian coordinates in Newtonian physics.